# convert output formula to value?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to convert function `fun(=SUMIF(B1:B16,B2,C1:C16))` into value so that I can use the output in another operation.

Moreover, I need to know which is the best module for working in excel and formatting cells.

```
 import openpyxl
 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('file.xlsx')
 ws = wb.active
 # add a simple formula
 ws['A3'] = ("=SUMIF(B1:B16,B2,C1:C16)")
 wb.save("file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a look at [pyparsing](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyparsing/1.5.7), but I  don't know, if it suits your needs best and can solve the given task.

Comment: Still not able to find answer
But anyway thanks for your comment